# How to output CSS counter from Sass mixin

Tags: css, sass, counter

I am writing a mixin that I want to output a CSS counter. Here's my goal:

```
.selector:nth-child(3n+1) {
  color: green;
}
```

That makes every three elements, starting with the first, green.
I would like my mixin to take that first number, in my example `3` and output the CSS. Something like this:

```
@mixin counter($number) {
  &:nth-child($number * n + 1) {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Is this possible in Sass at this point?

Comment: Yes just like you thought

Comment: I get this error: `invalid property name`

Comment: @icicleking: I don't have much experience with Sass but have you tried - `&:nth-child(#{$number}n + 1)`?

Comment: Oh yes the * is the problem. Try Harrys aporoach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable's value in the selector, you should use the [interpolation syntax `#{}`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) and append the `n` to it like in the below code block.

```
@mixin counter($number) {
  &:nth-child(#{$number}n + 1) {
    color: green;
  }
}
.selector{
  @include counter(3);
}
```

The above code compiles successfully and produces the required output when tested using the online compiler at [sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/).